# Alternating between two arraylists.

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble getting this thing to run. I'm not sure if what I have so far is on the right track. I'm not quite sure where is is giving me an out of bounds error.

Here are the instructions:

Write a method called interleave that accepts two ArrayLists of integers a1 and a2 as parameters and inserts the elements of a2 into a1 at alternating indexes. If the lists are of unequal length, the remaining elements of the longer list are left at the end of a1. For example, if a1 stores [10, 20, 30] and a2 stores [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], the call of interleave(a1, a2); should change a1 to store [10, 4, 20, 5, 30, 6, 7, 8]. If a1 had stored [10, 20, 30, 40, 50] and a2 had stored [6, 7, 8], the call of interleave(a1, a2); would change a1 to store [10, 6, 20, 7, 30, 8, 40, 50].

```
private static void interleave(ArrayList<Integer> a1,
        ArrayList<Integer> a2) {

    int i = a1.size();
    int j = a2.size();

    if (i < j) { // a1 is shorter than a2
        for (int k = 0; k < a1.size(); k++) { // before k passes a1 size
            a1.add(k+1, a2.get(k));
        }

        for (int l = a1.size(); l < a2.size(); l++) {
            a1.add(a1.size(), a2.get(l));
        }

    } else if (i > j) { // a1 is longer than a2
        for (int k = 1; k < a2.size(); k++) {
            a1.add(k+1, a2.get(k));
        }

    } else { // they are equal length
        for (int k = 1; k < a2.size(); k++) {
            a1.add(k+1, a2.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with a third `ArrayList`, insert the values from `a1` and `a2` into.  When you done, remove all the elements from `a1` and add all the elements from the temporary list to it...

Comment: Note that the way you've written it won't work because whenever you add an element to `a1`, that shifts all the indexes of all the _following_ elements, and you haven't adjusted for that when inserting.  Going in reverse order is one way around this problem.  Also, two of your loops start with `int k = 1` which will omit one of the elements.  I'm sure those aren't the only problems.  I'd recommend adding debugging code to print the current contents of `a1` every time you add something to it, which will help you track down any problems.

Comment: Another problem, and I think this is the one causing the out-of-bounds error: Every time you add to `a1`, `a1.size()` increases.  The `for` loops that use `a1.size()` don't take that into account.  They should be using the original value of `a1.size()` even after the size gets larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
private static void interleave(ArrayList<Integer> a1, ArrayList<Integer> a2) {
    int i = -1;
    for(Integer elem: a2) {
        if(i < a1.size()-1) {
            i += 2;
        } else {
            i += 1;
        }
        a1.add(i, elem);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30));
    ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8));

    interleave(a1, a2);
    System.out.println(a1);
}
```

edit: I have to admit, that this code is actually a pretty bad solution, because it's gonna be very slow for long lists. Every time an element is added to a1, a big part of the list has to be shifted by one position.
So following the advice from "MadProgrammer", here is a much better and much much faster way to do it

```
private static void interleave(ArrayList<Integer> a1, ArrayList<Integer> a2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>(a1.size() + a2.size());

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < a1.size() || j < a2.size(); i++, j++) {
        if(i < a1.size()) r.add(a1.get(i));
        if(j < a2.size()) r.add(a2.get(j));
    }
    a1.clear();
    a1.addAll(r);
}
```

Comment: Just my opinion, but when we're dealing with a homework assignment, I think it's usually best to try to help the questioner understand where they went wrong in their thinking--especially in a case like this where the questioner was on the right track but got some of the details wrong.  That way, they can learn how their thinking got a little bit off and how to fix it.  Giving them a complete replacement answer helps them learn **nothing**.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is great solution, insofar as it's using the `for ( Type x : ... ) { ... }` loop.  Since we need indexes here, it's actually more convenient to use index variables.

Comment: I understand now. I forgot about using a for-each loop instead of doing it the long, convoluted method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I see that there's already any accepted answer, but I think that this is a case where using a `for` loop with proper index variables will be more convenient than the `for` loop that works on arrays and collections.  For instance, look at what happens as this progress over time.  `a2` is always the same: `[4 5 6 7 8]`, and the indices of its elements that should be inserted into `a1` are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.  Now, the first element (`4`) should be inserted into `a1` at position `1`.  After that, the next element (`5`) needs to be inserted at position `3`. Then `6` needs to be inserted at position `5`.  In general, the `i`th element of `a2` needs to be inserted at position `i*2+1` in `a1`.  This will hold until either `i*2+1` is bigger than the number of elements in `a1`, or you run out of elements in `a2`.  With this taken into consideration, the proper index to insert the `i`th element of `a2` into `a1`, after all the earlier elements have been inserted, is `Math.min( i*2+1, l1.size() )`, since adding at `l1.size()` just adds an element to the end of the list.

I agree with [the comment about not giving away homework answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260820/alternating-between-two-arraylists#comment28514982_19260969), but since there's already an answer with a complete implementation, and I want to contrast the `for` with an index to the `for-each` loop, I'll include code here.  The updated `interleave` method is

```
public static <T> List<T> interleave( final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2 ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++ ) {
        l1.add( Math.min( i*2+1, l1.size()), l2.get( i ));
    }
    return l1;
}
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient implementation, though.  It would make more sense to finish the `for` loop when you get to the end of `l1` and simply add the remaining elements all at once.  I've also written this to take `List`s, since that's all the code depends on, though the random accessing with `get` will only be efficient on lists that support it efficiently (e.g., it will be fine for `ArrayList`s, but will perform poorly for linked lists).  The fact that these are just lists also suggests that you might consider a solution using [`ListIterator`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

In context, and with a `main` method that demonstrates it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Interleave {

    public static <T> List<T> interleave( final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2 ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < l2.size(); i++ ) {
            l1.add( Math.min( i*2+1, l1.size()), l2.get( i ));
        }
        return l1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 10, 20, 30 ) );
        final List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList( 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 );
        System.out.println( interleave( l1, l2 ));
    }
}
```

After thinking about this some more, I think that there's something to be said for using a `ListIterator` here.  It makes some of the iteration and insertion code a bit cleaner, especially since insertion with a `ListIterator` occurs *before* the iteration cursor.  It also doesn't require any complicated index arithmetic. Here's an implementation that uses the `ListIterators`:

```
public static <T> List<T> interleaveWithIterators( final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2 ) {
    // Get an iterator for the l1, and position it after the first element
    // or at the end, if there's no first element.
    final ListIterator<T> it1 = l1.listIterator();
    if ( it1.hasNext() ) { it1.next(); } 

    // Get an iterator for l2.  While there are elements remaining in l2, 
    // keep adding them to l1 by calling it1.add().  While there are elements
    // in l1, this also requires pushing it1 forward by one element on each iteration.
    final ListIterator<T> it2 = l2.listIterator();
    while ( it2.hasNext() ) {
        it1.add( it2.next() );
        if ( it1.hasNext() ) { it1.next(); }
    }
    return l1;
}
```

To avoid checking `if ( it1.hasNext() ) { ... }` on each iteration, you could split up the while loop:

```
public static <T> List<T> interleaveWithIterators( final List<T> l1, final List<T> l2 ) {
    final ListIterator<T> it1 = l1.listIterator();
    if ( it1.hasNext() ) { it1.next(); } 
    final ListIterator<T> it2 = l2.listIterator();
    while ( it2.hasNext() && it1.hasNext() ) {
        it1.add( it2.next() );
        it1.next();
    }
    while ( it2.hasNext() ) {
        it1.add( it2.next() );
    }
    return l1;
}
```

Comment: `l1.add( Math.min( i*2+1, l1.size()), l2.get( i ));` -- a line like that needs intermediate variables & a comment to be readable and maintainable. (Comment could also precede the loop.)

Comment: @ThomasW I thought that the paragraph of text in the answer leading up to the code would suffice as a comment. :)  But yes, it could be cleaned up, certainly.  I've added an implementation based on ListIterator that doesn't require such complicated index arithmetic.

Comment: I like this first form with the ListIterator, actually.. I've never seen much use/interest in the ListIterator prior to this. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
private static void interleave(ArrayList<Integer> 
a1, ArrayList<Integer> a2) {
int i = -1;
for(Integer elem: a2) {
    if(i < a1.size()-1) {
        i += 2;
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
    a1.add(i, elem);
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30));
ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8));

interleave(a1, a2);
System.out.println(a1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> alternate(LinkedList<Integer> list1, LinkedList<Integer> list2){
    List<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> itr1 = list1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> itr2 = list2.iterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext() || itr2.hasNext()){
        if (itr1.hasNext()){
            newList.add(itr1.next());
        }
        if (itr2.hasNext()){
            newList.add(itr2.next());
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```